# Flickering external monitor w/ MBP retina 13"

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi

I use the latest 13" MBP retina and I wanted to use an external display (LG IPS231) through hdmi but the LG doesn't have an HDMI port.

So, I plugged the HDMI cable into my laptop to an HDMI to DVI adapter which I, then, plug into the screen. That doesn't work. Both screens flicker when I plug and unplug the monitor and the MBP recognises the screen and its resolution. On the other hand, the monitor shows the no signal screen.

I don't have another monitor or other computer to test right now.

I included a picture, not sure if it's super helpful.

[image: pic]

Thanks in advance if anyone helps!

Answer (score 1):

All I can really suggest is that you purchase a [Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB572Z/B/mini-displayport-to-vga-adapter?fnode=51), along with a VGA cable (D-Sub cable), and use that with your MacBook Pro.

(the blue socket beneath the DVI socket is the VGA socket.)